# AndroidPlot and RectRegion behavior

Tags: java, android, charts, androidplot

Hello iam trying to show a rect for a bmi graph.

but the rect will be cut and hidden on scroll event

**EDIT:** the green rect should be

Point A(-infinity, 21)
Point B(+infinity, 21)
Point C(+infinity, 26)
Point D(-infinity, 26)

But Point B is (12.10, 21) //12.10 is a date 12-10-2012

```
    // optimal_range
    LineAndPointFormatter optFormat = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT);
    XYRegionFormatter rf = new XYRegionFormatter(optimal_color_fill);
    RectRegion rr = new RectRegion(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, optimal[0], optimal[1]);

    Number xDummy[] = { Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY };
    Number yDummy[] = { optimal[1], optimal[1] };
    XYSeries optSerie = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(xDummy), Arrays.asList(yDummy), "");
    mySimpleXYPlot.addSeries(optSerie, optFormat);
```

[image: Rect problem]

Comment: Could you be more specific? What are you expecting to see, we can't duplicate your issue without the same data or at least some sample data.

Comment: the green bar should be
xmin = -infinity  |  xmax = +infinity
ymin = 21.0  |  ymax = 26.0

so that the green rect will fill the whole chart on the x-axis
but the xmax/ymin coordinate isn't drawn right
-------------------------------------------------
if i scroll the chart and the green rect top corner ist off screen, the complete dummyChart will be hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a while since I looked at the code for this and I never did anything with regions but I think if you pan and zoom so that data is off the screen the points off screen are just not drawn and this leads to what you are seeing.  To get things correct there is a need to clip the line segment going off the screen to the screen edges.

Comment: thx, i changed the line:

Number xDummy[] = { Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, DateUtils.getBeforeNow(0, 0, -1) };

Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY caused the problem
(getBeforeNow returns the actual date minus year,month,day)